# Can not get data table row selection in PrimeFaces, jsf?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm working on a project. I need to get a list from MySql database and list it. I'm using JSF 2.1 Primeface 3.5 and Eclipse Juno. I run my code but it doesn't work. You can see my codes in below

```
     //LOGIN CLASS

    import parts
    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class Login {

private String username, password;
private PreparedStatement ps, ps2;
private ResultSet rs, rs2;
private List<Application> applications = new ArrayList<Application>();;
private Application selectedApplication;

// GETTERS SETTERS



public String login() {
    Connection object = new Connection();

    try {

        ps = nesne
                .getCon()
                .prepareStatement(
                        "select Username, Password from company where Username=? and Password=?");
        ps.setString(1, getUsername());
        ps.setString(2, getPassword());
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            getList();
            return "application";

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);

    }


    return "confirm";
}


private List<Application> getList() {
    Baglanti nesne = new Baglanti();
    try {

        ps2 = nesne
                .getCon()
                .prepareStatement(
                        "select ApplicationName from application where CompanyID=(select ID from company "
                                + "where Username=? and Password=?)");

        ps2.setString(1, getUsername());
        ps2.setString(2, getPassword());
        rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();


        while (rs2.next()) {
            Application obj = new Application();
            obj.setApplicationName(rs2.getString("ApplicationName"));
            applications.add(obj);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);

    }
    return applications;
}
```

APPLICATION CLASS

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Application {

private int ID;
private int CompanyID;
private String Type;
private Date Date;
private String ApplicationName;
private int CurrentMessageCount;
private int MaxMessage;
private String isPro;


    //GETTERS SETTERS
```

application.xhtml

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
   <h:head>
    <title>Login Confirmed</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" align="center">Application
    List</h1>
<br />
<h:form id="form">

    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

    <p:dataTable id="applications" var="application"
        value="#{login.applications}">

        <p:column headerText="Application" style="width:24%">
            <h:outputText value="#{login.applications}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width:4%">
            <p:commandButton id="selectButton" icon="ui-icon-search"
                title="View">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{application}"
                    target="#{login.selectedApplication}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>


</h:form>
```

I can login properly after that ı saw this page.
[image]
 Now where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `var="application"` is conflicting with the implicit EL object referring the application context (the `ServletContext`). [You can find here a list of all implicit EL objects](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects). Memorize them. You should never declare an EL variable on exactly those names.

Give it a different name. E.g. `var="app"`, `var="_application"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In data table var property mean that every item from database will be accesible as this "var" value. i.e:
You have class Foo:

```
class Foo{
int number;
String text;
//Setters and getters
}
```

And another class which handle list of Foo objects (your model as CDI Bean):

```
@Named
class Boo{
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();
//Getter and setters
}
```

So to list it all in jsf page you should use it like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="list" var="listobject" value="#{boo.list}">
   <p:column headerText="Number" style="width:24%">
      <h:outputText value="#{listobject.number}" />
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="Text" style="width:24%">
      <h:outputText value="#{listobject.String}" />
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

So summary "var" value is accessor string to boo object.

Look also:
[PrimeFaces datatable demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableBasic.jsf) and here
[Mkyong datatable tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  I have Application class as a your Foo class. And I have applications list in my Login class as a your Boo class. I said var="applications" and value="#{application.applicationName}" but it gives this error: HTTP Status 500 - /application.xhtml @22,60 value="#{application.applicationName}": Property 'applicationName' not found on type org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade

Comment: I don't know if you made a typo but if var = "applications" then value should be value="#{applications.applicationName}" not value="#{application.applicationName}"

Comment: Your Application class must have private fields with public setters and getters. Check also scope of your Application bean (Request/View/Scoped). If everything is correct please add some more data.